# explain the pattern s/\(b\?\)-/x\u\1/g in sed

Tags: sed, expression

The content given to sed is below:

a-b-

Below is tried sed syntax;

```
s/\(b\?\)-/x\u\1/g
```

the third is an output

```
axxB
```

I want to know how it matches. I can't understand 'b\?'. What does it mean? Does'\?' just mean '?'

Comment: `b\?-` will match `-` or `b-` ... `?` is a quantifier which will greedily match zero or one time, in this case the character `b`

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax

Comment: thanks for the website

Answer (score 1):

`s/regex/replacement/g` is the basic structure of your command, you can read about it here:

`man sed | sed -n '/^\s\{7\}s\//,/exp.$/p'`

Since `sed` reads line be line, there is the option `g`, which you can append to `s///`, for that to match every occurence of `regex` in a line and not only the first. That's why you have:
`s/regex/replacement/g`

Your `regex`:

If you read the hint from above in `man sed` you can notice it is possible to group the replacement. If you want that, you need a group in your `regex` and the syntax af a group is `\(\)`, at least you have to notice that meta characters have to be escaped with an ordinary backslash `\`.

In your regex group you are looking for the character `b` witch will be matched at most once because of the given repetition `\?`, which also have to be ecaped and is just a short form of `\{0,1\}`.

The last character you have in your regex is a dash `-`.

So you are looking for `\(b\?\)-`, a group with zero or one `b` and a dash.

Your `replacement`:

The groups of your regex can be referenced in the replacement with a backslash followed by the number of the group. This is your `\1`.

While you are using `GNU sed` you have the extension `\u` which turns the next character to upper case. You can read about this here: [3.3 The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

So after you have put your regex group in your replacement to the end and will turn it to upper case you finally replace every dash, because of your `g` flag in `s///`, with the ordinary character `x`.

So your replacement is `x\u\1`.

That is why you have:

```
$ echo "a-b-" | sed 's/\(b\?\)-/x\u\1/g'
axxB
```